# Why is Django cms sitemap url not matching in all browsers?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Using the testing server `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/sitemap.xml` correctly returns an XML sitemap in Firefox  but in Chrome I get a 404. Why is this?

All other pages' urls route OK in Chrome but this is what I get for the site map:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mycms.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    ^media/(?P<path>.*)$
    ^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
    ^en/ ^admin/
    ^en/ ^sitemap\.xml$
    ^en/ ^select2/
    ^en/ ^ ^cms_wizard/
    ^en/ ^ ^(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-_.//]+)/$ [name='pages-details-by-slug']
    ^en/ ^ ^$ [name='pages-root']
    ^en/ ^ ^forms/submit/$ [name='djangocms_forms_submissions']
    The current URL, /en/sitemap.xml/, didn't match any of these.
```

My `urls.py` is

```
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',
        {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
    url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),
    # url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='polls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('djangocms_forms.urls')),
)

# This is only needed when using runserver.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',  # NOQA
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        ) + staticfiles_urlpatterns() + urlpatterns  # NOQA
```

Safari tries to format it, but seems to GET the sitemap OK. It looks fine in Firefox:

```
<urlset>
    <url>
        <loc>http://example.com/en/</loc>
        <lastmod>2016-11-22</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://example.com/en/aboutus/</loc>
        <lastmod>2016-11-22</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        ...
</urlset>
```

Comment: nothing to do with chrome really, you are typing an extra '/' at the end of the url. (and I am guessing whenever you try it now, autocomplete is giving you that '/' almost by force :) )

Comment: How right you are! How foolish I feel!

Answer (score 3):

for all those who are still wondering what that "/" means than simply update the url

**from**

```
url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',
        {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
```

**to**

```
url(r'^sitemap\.xml/$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',
        {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe I spent so much time not noticing that the final `/` was the cause of the problem.
I'll leave this post here just in case it saves someone else some time ...